# NuxtLink @click action before routing

Tags: nuxt.js, routerlink, nuxt-link

I need to run a method before NuxtLink navigates to a route. In the method I want to decide whether to release it or not. Like in vanilla JS:

```html
<a href="some-page" onclick="return count > 10 ? true : false">Done</a>
```

I know how to stop NuxtLink and run the method instead, but how do I pause it, make some actions and decide whether to release it or not?

Comment: Hm, at the end if you're not navigating to some place, why not just use a regular `button` + `@click` combo here? Seems like a lot of work for this use case. Also, how do you cancel a navigation with a nuxt-link as of right now?

Comment: In some cases I need to navigate to Nuxt routes (`pages/some-page`) and in other I need to do some actions before.
Cancel NuxtLink: `<nuxt-link :to="{ ... }" @click.native="action" event="">`

Comment: So, why don't you get the test into the action, then move forward if the conditions are met?

Comment: This is the question. This method completely stops the default behavior of NuxtLink. I don't know how to release it to routing

Comment: In the method, you can use `$router.push` based on the location of your `:to` prop IMO, you don't have such thing in your `action($event)` state?

Comment: Yes I can, but I thought that there should be a default way like in vanilla JS

Comment: Using `$router` is pretty much the default in a Vue context.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `@click.native` with `NuxtLink` and `RouterLink`.

So, your code should look like this

```html
<NuxtLink @click.native='clickAction()' to='/my-page'>
  Some link text
</NuxtLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt3:

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>
  const anyFunction = () => {
    console.log('easy')
  }
</script>

<template>
  <NuxtLink
    :to="'/'"
    @click.prevent="anyFunction()"
  >easy</NuxtLink>
</template>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).